# Color bar in Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently working on a project and I can't seem to get my colorbar to change its scale in the top left to corner. I also have an issue with editing the labels at the bottom of the graph. I am fairly new to coding and mostly do it for biological data so I apologize for a noob question.

What image is supposed to look like:

[image: What image is supposed to look like]

What mine currently looks like:

[image: What mine currently looks like]

Code:

```
data1 = np.random.randn(10000, 3)
data2 = np.random.randn(10000, 3) + 2
results1 = ttest_ind(data1, data2, axis=1)
data3 = np.random.randn(10000, 3)
data4 = np.random.randn(10000, 3)
results2 = ttest_ind(data3, data4, axis=1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(8, 7))
axes[0,0].set(ylabel='Genes',yticks=[],xticks=[])
axes[1,0].set(ylabel='Genes',yticks=[],xticks=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
axes[0,1].set(ylabel='Frequency', ylim=(0,6000), yticks=[0, 2000, 4000, 6000], xticks=[])
axes[1,1].set(ylabel='Frequency',xlabel='p-value', ylim=(0,6000),yticks=[0, 2000, 4000, 6000],xticks=[0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])
```

## heatmap

```
axes[0][0].imshow(np.hstack((data1, data2)), aspect='auto', cmap='seismic', vmin=-5, vmax=5)
axes[1][0].imshow(np.hstack((data3, data4)), aspect='auto', cmap='seismic', vmin=-5, vmax=5)

im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='seismic', vmin=-4, vmax=4)
cax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.04])
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
```

Comment: So the question is how to control the size of the colorbar? You want to make it smaller?

Comment: no sir, i would like to change the scale from increments of -1 to -4, -2, 0, 2, 4 and would like some guidance on how to create the right two figures. something to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `set_ticks` method, e.g.,

```
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax, orientation='horizontal')
cbar.set_ticks([-4, -2, 0, 2, 4])
```

Comment: `plt.hist(data_to_be_histogrammed)` see https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html